# phpmailer throwing intermittent error : EOF found while checking if connected

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail via SMTP using PHPMailer class. My problem is , for the first attempt , the mail sender is working oerfect , but for all subsequent attempts it's throwing error :

```
SMTP -> NOTICE:
   EOF caught while checking if connected
```

My email sending code is :

```
function  sendEmail($toAddress,$fromAddress,$toName,$fromName,$subject,$emailContent,$content_type = false, $attach_path="", $cc = '', $cc_name="")
{
        require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        if (empty($content_type)) $content_type = false;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();            // set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth = MY_SMTP_AUTH;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Host   = MY_SMTP_HOST_NAME;

        if (!empty($this->smtpEncryptionMode))
        {
                $mail->SMTPSecure= $this->smtpEncryptionMode;
        }
        if (!empty ($this->smtpPort))
        {
                $mail->Port = MY_SMTP_PORT;
        }
        else $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->Username = $this->smtpUserName;
        $mail->Password = $this->smtpUserPassword;
        $mail->From     =$fromAddress;
        $mail->FromName = $fromName;

            if(is_array($toAddress))
                {
                        foreach($toAddress as $to)
                        {
                                $mail->AddAddress($to, "" );
                        }
                }
                else
                {
        $mail->AddAddress($toAddress, $toName );
                }
        $mail->AddReplyTo($fromAddress, $fromName );
        $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->WordWrap = 80;  // set word wrap to 80 characters
        $mail->IsHTML($content_type);  // set email format to basic
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $emailContent;
        //Here it sets other parameters e.g attachment path etc.
        $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
        $result = $mail->Send();
        if($result == false ) { $result = $mail->ErrorInfo;echo $result; }// Switch   this on when debugging.
        return $result;
```

Why is it throwing the error for all successive attempts?

From , what I can infer from class.smtp.php is that it is failing inside a function **Connected()** which actually checks the socket status of the smtp_connection instance, and there it is getting EOF.

I guess the connection itself isnot getting established...But what is going right in the first instance then?

Answer (score 0):

Is the function in a while loop and if so you need to close the class. Might be to easy try this.

```
$result = $mail->Send(); 
$mail->close();
```

Comment: I tried using **$mail->SmtpClose()** but it didn't work.Could it be a problem on the smtp server side ? How can I verify that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't send to mail instances at once for example you call test_mail() and then emailer() function test_mail uses another connection while the other function uses phpmailer and is connected to port 465. Now emailer will throw an EOF error because the connection on the first function is not yet exited.

```
/*function test_mail(){
    $to = 'emil.nrqz@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Test email using PHP'; 
    $message = 'This is a test email message'; $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-fwebmaster@example.com'); 

}*/

function emailer($sendby,$subject,$body,$sendto,$cc){
    require("../obj/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();                    // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP();                            // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                       // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // authentication enabled
    $mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Port = 25;                           // or 587 or 465

    /*
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // authentication enabled
    $mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Port = 465;                      // or 587 or 465
    */

    //var_dump($mail);exit();
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                        // sends email as html
    $mail->Username = MAILER_USERNAME;  // mailserver username
    $mail->Password = MAILER_PASSWORD;              // mailserver password
    $mail->SetFrom("info@file-bird.com");                   // Seen as message from
    $mail->Subject = $subject;                  // Subject of the message
    $mail->Body = $body;                        // email body - can be html
    $mail->AddAddress($sendto);                 // where email will be sent
    $mail->addCC($cc);

    if(!$mail->Send()){
        return "Mailer Error: "; // . $mail->ErrorInfo
    }
    else{
        return "Message has been sent";
        $mail->close();
    }
}
```